# Communication between HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync and MVC controller actions

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a C# controller that should make an asyncronous call to another remote controller sending a simple object (model):

```cs
HttpClient clientHTTP = new HttpClient();
myModel model = new myModel();
model.Id = 100; 
model.data = "this is data";
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

clientHTTP.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://REMOTE_IP/");
clientHTTP.PostAsJsonAsync("/WebcastNotify/Heat", json)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
```

The remote controller:

```cs
public class WebcastNotifyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Heat(myModel model)
    {
       // allways recieve model.Id = 0 and model.data = null
    }
}
```

And the simple model:

```cs
public class modeloWebCast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  data { get; set; }
}
```

Why I getting allways and empty object at remote controller (model.id = 0, model.data=null)

Like peopple suggested, If i pass the model variable directly, I recieve null object (not object with null properties like before) in the controller.

I tried to use a simple html page to test:

```cs
function Send()
{
    var Url = "@Url.Action("Heat", "WebcastNotify")";

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "post",
        url: Url,
        ajaxasync: true,
        data: {modelo:{ Id: 100, data: "this is the data"}},
        success: function (result) {
            $("#CapaInfo").html(result);
        }
    })
}
```

And with this code the object is sent to the controller perfectly.

What can i doing wrong?

Comment: If I pass the object directly without serialize them the controller recieves a null object

Comment: I suggest you to try first calling the controller directly from any http request generator like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). If you can't get the controller to get an object from a correct request, then the problem is in the controller, and you should fix that first. I agree with the other 2 answers though, you should pass the model directly to 'PostAsJsonAsync'.

Comment: I tried with a simple tml - js page:
        var UrlDestino = "@Url.Action("Heat", "WebcastNotify")";
        
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "post",
            url: UrlDestino,
            ajaxasync: true,
            data: {modelo:{ Id: 100, modelo: "this is data"}},
            success: function (result) {
                $("#CapaInfo").html(result);
            }
        })
And it goes well.

Answer (score 2):

`PostAsJsonAsync()` takes an object to serialize as JSON.

You're passing it a string (which happens to be serialized JSON), so it serializes that to a JSON string (`"..."`).

You need to pass it the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `PostAsJsonAsync` method accepts a normally typed value and does not expect it to have already been serialized.

See [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync%60%601%28System.Net.Http.HttpClient,System.Uri,%60%600%29).

Try passing the `model` variable directly.

Comment: I tried but if I pass directly the model variable then null value arrives the controller.

Comment: @Pila77 that sounds like an issue with the controller.  You probably need to post another question to get help on that one.